# Using Angular <a routerLink="">, I am not able to perform navigation as <a href="">

Tags: angular

Using 
     `<a href="abc.html">`
it easily redirects to the abc.html page.
I have to do the same using:
HTML file:
      `<a routerLink="/product">`
Angular 4 module ts file: app-routing.module.ts

```
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'product', component: ProductComponent}
];
```

Product.component.ts looks like this:

```
@Component({
     selector: 'app-product',
     templateUrl: './product.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['../styles/main.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Using this Angular code, the Product page is not loaded, it includes the product page into existing page from where we click on this link. Please help me get the same as `<a href>` tag.

Comment: try <a [routerLink]="['product']" >

Comment: see here https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Where is your `router-outlet` directive located?

Comment: Hi Bunyamin,

    <div>
    <a  routerLink="/batch" title="Manage Batch" class="">                     <span>Manage Batch</span></a>
     <a  routerLink="/product" title="Manage Product" class="">  <span>Manage Product</span></a>
       </div>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: @Ricardo, I used the same but it is not redirecting a fesh request to Product. It adds the Product page content into existing Dashboard(Home) Page

Comment: @Tauqir, thanks I'll go throught that link

Comment: can you include your router file? or the structure of your router?

Comment: Make sure `RouterModule` is imported in your `AppModule` or in the module where you have this componenet declared. Without the `RouterModule`, routerLink will not work. Additionally, your routes should also be configured.

Comment: @Ricardo, Please find the screen shot of routing file on the below path  https://imgur.com/a/C4Bc0

Comment: @Faisal and Ricardo,this is the app-routing.module.ts                 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'product', component: ProductComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Comment: as I said earlier, you need to import `RouterModule` in your `AppModule`

Comment: @Failsal, import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; it is imported